# Variable not defined when file updating

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python and I am making a tennis coach program. On the option 3 where you can update it is not working as it says nameUnder is not defined in the else statement. Please help as I really don't understand why its not working. I have also tries it without the split but that to doesn't work

```
import os, sys
print("Please select an option:")
print("[1] Add a student")
print("[2] Read a students data")
print("[3] Update a students data")
print("[4] Delete a students data")
menuSelect = int(input("Make your number selection: "))
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if menuSelect == 1:
    amountDone=0
    amounttodo=int(input("Enter the number of contestants you would like to add: "))


    while amounttodo>amountDone:
        ageOne=int(input("Enter the age of the contestant: "))
        if ageOne <= 11:
            underFile=open("Under11s.txt","a")
            nameUnder=input("Enter the first name of the student: ")
            genderUnder=input("Enter the gender of the student: ")
            posUnder=int(input("Input the last position of the student: "))
            underFile.write("\n"+str(nameUnder) + " | " + str(genderUnder) + " | " + str(posUnder))
            underFile.close()
            amountDone=amountDone+1
        elif ageOne >= 12:
            overFile=open("Over11s.txt","a")
            nameOver=input("Enter the first name of the student: ")
            genderOver=input("Enter the gender of the student: ")
            posOver=int(input("Input the last position of the student: "))
            overFile.write("\n"+str(nameOver) + " | " + str(genderOver) + " | " + str(posOver))
            overFile.close()
            amountDone=amountDone+1
        else:
            print("Invalid, Please enter a number")
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

elif menuSelect == 2:
    print("Enter the file you would like to open.")
    print("1) Under 11's")
    print("2) Over 11's")
    fileToOpen=int(input("Enter the number of your selection: "))
    if fileToOpen == 1:
        f = open("Under11s.txt", "r")
        file_contents = f.read()
        print(file_contents)
    elif fileToOpen == 2:
        f = open("Over11s.txt", "r")
        file_contents = f.read()
        print(file_contents)
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
elif menuSelect == 3:
    studentName = input("Enter the student name you are looking for:") 
    file = open("Under11s.txt","r")
    found=False 
    for line in file:
        details = line.split(",") 
        writefile = open("Under11supdated.txt","a")
        details = line.split(",")
        if details[0] == studentName:
            found=True 
            nameUnder=input("Enter the first name of the student: ")
            genderUnder=input("Enter the gender of the student: ")
            posUnder=int(input("Input the last position of the student: "))
            file.write("\n"+str(nameUnder)[0] + " | " + str(genderUnder)[1] + " | " + str(posUnder)[2])
        else:
            file.write("\n"+nameUnder[0] + " | " + genderUnder[1] + " | " + posUnder[2])
        file.close() 
    file.close()
    os.remove("Under11s.txt") 
    os.rename("Under11supdated.txt","Under11s.txt")
    if found==True: 
        print("Details updated") 
    else:
        print("That student cannot be found in the file, no changes made") 
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

else:
    print("Sorry, this option is not available yet!")
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: It is created in the `if`, and so it's scope is only in the `if`. The `else` is outside of this scope.

Comment: So how do I fix it? Sorry i am new to programming xD

Comment: You need to set it in the `else` itself, or before the `if`.

Comment: Set what in the else?

Comment: The variavle `nameUnder`

Answer (score 0):

`nameUnder` only gets defined if this statement is true `if details[0] == studentName:`

Not a 100% of your logic here, but make sure to set `nameUnder= ""` before the if statement so the variable is declared and can be used in your else clause.

I would recommend you to structure your code with functions for the each options etc., will make it easier to read and possible reuse some of the code.

Partly updated code:

```
writefile = open("Under11supdated.txt","a")
details = line.split(",")
nameUnder = ""
if details[0] == studentName:
    found=True 
    nameUnder=input("Enter the first name of the student: ")
    genderUnder=input("Enter the gender of the student: ")
```

Comment: I think this is like doing `except: pass`... Your'e ignoring the logical problem of not defining what should `nameUnder` be if `details[0] != studentName`. (Unless, of course, `""` is the desired value)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I'm stating I don't really understand his logic  and I'm not trying to improve his overall program, I am giving the answer to his question why he gets an undefined error.